# Word to describe a person who spends extremely little money

Tags: word-request

What do you call a person who spends extremely little money, and is careful in spending each and every dollar? Note, I'm not saying he has little money. He spends very, very little money, but he has lots more money than he spends. For example, he can easily afford to have a $25 dinner, but he never spends more than $8 for dinner. He can afford to buy a shirt for $30, but he has never bought a shirt for more than $10. What do you call this person? What are all the different words available? I'm looking for a word that's kind of insulting also. The word should also insult the person's behavior.

Comment: The first few words come to mind: *frugal*, *thrifty*, and perhaps *economical*.

Comment: @DamkerngT. - Your suggestions were excellent, pre-edit. (Another great example of why it is so important to **provide ample context** and example usages in questions.)

Answer (score 18):

There are quite a few words that can be insulting about someone who doesn't like to spend money.

A [miser](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/miser?show=0&t=1393635256) is

> a mean grasping person; especially :  one who is extremely stingy
>   with money

"[stingy](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stingy)" is also kind of insulting, as it describes someone who is "not generous",

> not liking or wanting to give or spend money

A [scrooge](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scrooge) is someone who is a miser and stingy:

> her father is a real scrooge and refuses to pay her way through
>   college, even though he can easily afford it

This word comes from the Charles Dickens story *[A Christmas Carol](http://www.sparknotes.com/lit/christmascarol/summary.html)* - Ebenezer  Scrooge is a rich but very mean man who makes his employees work long hours for little pay.

Here's a picture of someone in the role of Mr Scrooge:

[image: scrooge]

A "[tightwad](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tightwad)" and a "[cheapskate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cheapskate)" are also people who don't like to spend money. These words are a bit less negative, though: the person may not like to share or help others, but they are not as mean as a miser or a scrooge.

"[cheap](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cheap)" is another good word. It is also used for things of poor quality, so it suggests a person of low morals or class who is also stingy.

Comment: People can be stingy with things other than money. Affection, compliments, food, etc. I think stingy has a connotation of withholding something that's not difficult for you to give and is the opposite of generous. I think someone could be cheapskate, and not be stingy. Likewise, someone could be a [spendthrift](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/spendthrift "One who spends money recklessly or wastefully") and still be stingy.

Comment: *Scrooge* also has connotations related to Christmas itself (based on the Dickens character's attitudes towards the holiday). In some contexts, *scrooge* can mean *humbug*, or someone who lacks holiday cheer.

Comment: Exactly! That's what the OP was looking for.

Answer (score 6):

If you mean this in a positive way, use Damkerng T's words: frugal, thrifty, economical.

If you mean it in a negative way, use nxx's words: miserly, cheap, cheapskate, tightwad.

There's also "niggardly", but this seems to be falling out of use due to its unfortunate coincidental resemblance to a well-known racial slur.

Comment: Yeah... that last one really isn't worth mentioning for exactly the reason you mention.

Comment: @Catija It's a fine word to use as long as its used around at least moderately educated or well read people, though.  It has absolutely nothing to do with the slur besides sharing a similar beginning phoneme in many dialects.  You can read more about the issues with using it among the less educated at Wikipedia.

Answer (score 3):

A [Skinflint](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/skinflint) or a [penny-pincher](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/penny-pincher) would do.

Comment: I have never heard ''skinflint'' in my life.