# A Noun with a positive connotation for a person that is thrifty?

Tags: nouns

Related:
[Word to describe a person who spends extremely little money](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/18262/word-to-describe-a-person-who-spends-extremely-little-money)

This is different from that question, in that it is requesting

1.) a noun.

2.) a positive connotation on the noun.

Answer (score 2):

The positive word for someone who is careful with money is **frugal**.

> When we were growing up we didn't have much money, but my mother was very *frugal* and so while we didn't always have the things we *wanted*, we always managed to have everything we *needed*.

*Thrifty* is also positive.  *Economize* can also be used in some contexts.

> Ever since Bob was laid off we've had to *economize* to make ends meet.  But I think, although we don't have much money, in many ways we're happier than ever.

The idiomatic expression is **penny-pinching**.  This is somewhat more neutral and so the tone can vary with context,

> Mr. Jones *pinched every penny* he made -- he lived in a small apartment, took the bus to work, and only ate out once each week, on Sunday, at the same small cafe, where he always ordered the same thing: meatloaf (one of the cheaper items on the menu), with a small side potato, cole slaw, and a glass of water.  So when he retired he had saved enough to buy himself a yacht and sail around the world.

Of course there are many, many negative words for the same trait.

Comment: frugal = adjective, thrifty = adj, economize = verb, and then Penny pincher = noun, negative connotation: https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/penny-pincher

Comment: Ah, yeah.  Oops.  Penny-pincher is probably the closest.

Answer (score 2):

Since you ask for a noun with positive connotations:

> He was a **saver**, carefully considering every purchase, not a spendthrift.

But it would need context to distinguish it from someone who saves everything, a "hoarder".